# List View Showing Redundent data in android

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-listfragment

Sorry For asking this question again but i dont get any solution in previous question so srry again 
i am get duplicates data while i build and run the project on emulator 
here is my code for

**railcode.java**

```
public class RailCode extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

String[] member_names;
String[] contactType;

List<RowCode> rowCode;
ListView mylistview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.railcode);

    rowCode = new ArrayList<RowCode>();

    member_names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.member_names);


    contactType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.contactType);

    for (int i = 0; i < member_names.length; i++) {
        RowCode code = new RowCode(member_names[i],contactType[i]);
        rowCode.add(code);
    }

    mylistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, rowCode);
    mylistview.setAdapter(adapter);
    mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {
    String member_name = rowCode.get(position).getMember_name();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + member_name,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }

}
```

**CustonAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
List<RowCode> rowItems;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<RowCode> rowItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItems = rowItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rowItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return rowItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

/* private view holder class */
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView member_name;

    TextView contactType;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_code, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.member_name = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.member_name);
        holder.contactType = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.contact_type);

        RowCode row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

        holder.member_name.setText(row_pos.getMember_name());
        holder.contactType.setText(row_pos.getContactType());

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    return convertView;
}

}
```

Please help me i cannot understand y its showing duplicate data
Thanks in advance !!!!!1

Comment: Move the `RowCode` and `holder.*.setText()` lines to _after_ the `if-else` block, before the `return`.

Comment: not an issue paresh..

Comment: Thank you mike i got it right now no redundent data :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_code, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.member_name = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.member_name);
            holder.contactType = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.contact_type);



            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
// put here ..... after else condition
            RowCode row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

            holder.member_name.setText(row_pos.getMember_name());
            holder.contactType.setText(row_pos.getContactType());

    return convertView;
    }
```

Hope its worked

Comment: mike ans me early then you and you have copy it answer

Comment: @Paresh please check again you will find that .. i have put RowCode row_pos = rowItems.get(position); line outside if else condition.

Comment: you can not put RowCode row_pos = rowItems.get(position); line inside if condition .. because when if condition gets false then you get duplicate data......................................... previous assigned data.

Comment: mike has said that too you can see that in first comment of my question

Comment: i haven't read his comment i just checked his answer i found the mistake. so i just correct it :)

Answer (score 0):

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
Context context;
List<RowCode> rowItems;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<RowCode> rowItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItems = rowItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rowItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return rowItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

/* private view holder class */
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView member_name;

    TextView contactType;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_code, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.member_name = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.member_name);
        holder.contactType = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.contact_type);

        RowCode row_pos = rowItems.get(position);



        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
        holder.member_name.setText(row_pos.getMember_name());
        holder.contactType.setText(row_pos.getContactType());
    return convertView;
}

}
```